# While taking database backup in admin, Frontend Shows Fatal Error in Magento 1.9.3.3

Tags: magento-1.9, database

When I take database backup in admin
[image]

while the database backup is in progres, the loading sign appears in admin and  the frontend shows this error
[image]

instead of showing maintenance page to any user who visit the site during the backup process.
As soon as the database backup finish, the frontend returns back to normal

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 1, the alternative solution is to take the **Scheduled back up** and set the scheduled backup in **Night time** by `System > COnfiguration > Advanced > System > Scheduled backup settings`

[image]

For Magento 2 : `Magento > Shops > Configuration > Advanced > System > Settings for scheduled Backup`